# Filtering GroupJoin Query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a GroupJoin Query that returns a result like this:

```
IEnumerable<ICD.ViewModels.HomeSearchViewModel> query = ICDUnitOfWork.AlphaGroups.Find()
    .GroupJoin(ICDUnitOfWork.Alphas.Find(),
        a => a.AlphaGroupID,
        g => g.AlphaGroupID,
        (alphaGroups, alphas) =>
            new ICD.ViewModels.HomeSearchViewModel
            {
                AlphaGroups = alphaGroups,
                Alphas = alphas
            });
```

Alphas is `IEnumerable` and an AlphaGroup contains multiple Alphas.  They both have a property called "Title".  I need to filter the results based on the "Title" property for either containing the string "baby".  How can I accomplish this?

Edit: I should also mention that if a particular alpha group title contains "baby" that all corresponding Alphas with the AlphaGroupID should be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Entity Framework >= 4, then `Contains` will work:

```
.Where(row => 
    row.AlphaGroups.Title.Contains("baby") 
        || row.Alphas.Any(alpha => alpha.Title.Contains("baby"))
 );
```

---

**Edit** Updated to pre-filter the alphas in the grouping.  The final filter excludes rows that contain no alphas (indicating that *neither* the AlphaGroup title, *nor any* of the Alphas contain the string).

```
IEnumerable<ICD.ViewModels.HomeSearchViewModel> query = ICDUnitOfWork.AlphaGroups.Find()
    .GroupJoin(ICDUnitOfWork.Alphas.Find(),
        a => a.AlphaGroupID,
        g => g.AlphaGroupID,
        (alphaGroups, alphas) =>
            new ICD.ViewModels.HomeSearchViewModel
            {
                AlphaGroups = alphaGroups,
                Alphas = alphas.Where(alpha 
                    => alphaGroups.Title.Contains("baby")
                        || alpha.Title.Contains("baby"))
            });
    .Where(row => row.Alphas.Any());
```

Comment: I should also mention that if a particular alpha group title contains "baby" that all corresponding Alphas with the AlphaGroupID should be displayed.

Comment: @user547794 cool ... I believe my query above already does that, so ... lucky guess.

Comment: It's close, but when an Alpha.Title contains the string baby it should only show the Alpha's that contain "baby", rather than every alpha in the AlphaGroup.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Would recommend against `.Any()` as can map to nested unions, instead just filter pre-joining

Try

```
IEnumerable<ICD.ViewModels.HomeSearchViewModel> query = 
     ICDUnitOfWork.AlphaGroups.Find()
                  .Where(g => g.Title.Contains("baby"))
                  .GroupJoin(ICDUnitOfWork.Alphas.Find()
                                          .Where(a => a.Title.Contains("baby"),
                             a => a.AlphaGroupID,
                             g => g.AlphaGroupID,
                             (alphaGroups, alphas) =>
                                new ICD.ViewModels.HomeSearchViewModel
                                 {
                                  AlphaGroups = alphaGroups,
                                  Alphas = alphas
                                 }).AsEnumerable();
```